# How to repeat a html element inside a container div after every given height(say after every 10cm) for the given height of the container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to create a component in angular which is like an A4 Paper.

As the user enters content into it, the paper expands as I have set only the min-height of the div to 29.7cm.

**Note: This element is using only a single div. Adding multiple div blocks for each page would break the flow of content between pages when a user is editing.**

I would like to display a page number at the bottom as the user enters content into it after every 27.9cm. The page number should be a non editable content in the div.

Is this possible with a pure html and CSS soultion? or is it only possible with a new angular component?

The element looks like this.

Thanks in advance.

StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/github/rahulgul8/paper

The expected paper looks like this.

[image]

Note the page numbers in red.

as the user types in further and when the 29.7cm is reached again, the element adds the page number 3 again to the end of the page.

Comment: why don't you keep the page container height and max-length for input/textarea defined and place a page number text at bottom corner as soon as the text length becomes greater or equal to some fixed value?

Comment: But that would make the page number text as editable as well. I will update the question for this.

Comment: Not if you add pageNumber as part of another child div/span inside your page! and style it as you need

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your sample code, you can add page numbers to your `div` by inclding these styles

```
div:after {
  content:attr(data-page);
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  color:red;
}
```

And by adding `data-page="1"` to your div element